# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime if I change the date to be parsed

Tags: datetime, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I have two if statements in my razor code.  They both parse a date in the format `"hardcoded month/hardcoded day/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()` and display an action link if the date is between the two days.

It works perfectly when the first compare date is set to `"10/01/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString()`.
If I change it to `"07/01"`, then I get:

> FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

I have tried `Parse`, `ParseExact`, and `TryParse`.
All three methods fail if the date is set to July 1, whether I use `7/1`, `07/01`, or `7/01`.

This works:

```
@if (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(("10/1/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString())) && DateTime.Now < DateTime.Parse("03/31" + (DateTime.Now.Year + 1)))
{
    @:Action
}
```

This does not:

```
@if (DateTime.Now > DateTime.Parse(("7/1/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString())) && DateTime.Now < DateTime.Parse("03/31" + (DateTime.Now.Year + 1)))
{
    @:Action
}
```

I expect `7/1/2019` to parse to a year just the same as `10/1/2019` does.

Comment: you have to specifiy a format. it could be july 1st or january 7th

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
@{
    DateTime dateTime1 = DateTime.Parse("7/1/" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());
    string yr = (DateTime.Now.Year + 1).ToString();
    DateTime dateTime2 = DateTime.Parse("03/31/" + yr);
}

@if (DateTime.Now > dateTime1 && DateTime.Now < dateTime2)
{
    @:Action
}
```

Comment: Perfect.  This also made me realize that I had business rules in my view logic.  I've moved that to the controller and am passing a boolean called ViewBag.editable